# Modificar registro segun fecha en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, update

Estoy tratando de modificar registros en el cual apartir de una fecha busque los registros y los actualice, esta es la consulta....

```sql
UPDATE 
  entrada 
SET idReactivo = 2
  , idUnidadMedida = 1
  , idConcepto = 1
  , idMarca = 1 
WHERE 
fechaEntrada = fechaEntrada
```

Esta es la tabla donde quiero hacer el update...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres validar que sea a patir de una fecha estatica entonces lo debes hacer con `>=` quedando tu consulta de la siguiente manera

```
UPDATE entrada SET idReactivo = 2, idUnidadMedida = 1, idConcepto = 1, idMarca = 1 WHERE fechaEntrada >= fechaValidacion
```

Donde `fechaValidacion` es una String en formato `yyyy-mm-dd` y corresponde al dia minimo, por ejemplo, si quiero obtener todos los registros generados desde el primero de mayo de 2020 entonces quedaria asi `... WHERE fechaEntrada >= "2020-05-01"`

Comment: Pero no se puede decir que sea a la misma fecha, osea por ejemplo hay dos registros con el mismo idReactivo y la misma fecha, no es posible decirle que cuando las fechas sean iguales a ese primer registro???

Comment: A no dale, gracias, ya creo saber como lo implementare, hare una consulta antes para conseguir la fecha y luego se la paso como lo muestras tu, muchas gracias compa

Comment: Claro, de hecho no es muy buena idea que compares una fecha consigo misma por que siempre va a dar que son iguales a no ser que sean fechas de tablas diferenties

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que el WHERE dependerá del tipo de dato que almacena ese campo, pueden ser **DATE, DATETIME, TIME, TIMESTAMP**, en tu caso es un tipo **DATE** y el formato es **YYYY-MM-DD**, tu sentencia sql sería por ejemplo:

```sql
UPDATE 
  entrada 
SET idReactivo = 2
  , idUnidadMedida = 1
  , idConcepto = 1
  , idMarca = 1 
WHERE 
  fechaEntrada = '2020-06-02'
```

Esto actualizaría tus registros con id (1,2).

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás realizando la comparación con la misma fecha. Para esto te recomiendo separar los datos ya que fechaEntrada siempre va a ser igual a fechaEntrada. Cambia el nombre de la que deseas validar, ejemplo por @fechaValidacion date y de ahí puedes comparar si deben ser iguales (=), mayor o menor que(>,<) ó mayor igual que o menor igual que(>=,<=):

```
UPDATE entrada SET idReactivo = 2, idUnidadMedida = 1, idConcepto = 1, idMarca = 1 WHERE fechaEntrada >= @fechaValidacion
```

En este caso sería esa comparación

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda